# formula transfer to a new line

Tags: equations, line-breaking

How I can make a transfer of a long math equation in a new line? I suppose there are at least two methods: manually by hands and adjust math container to do that automatically. Can you show me, please this two methods.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post an example of an equation that you need to get broken across two or more lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make an equation centered on its own line, put it inside `\[...\]`.

If you want to break a long equation across many lines, the [`align`](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Align_%28environment%29) environment from the `amsmath` package is a great tool.

Here is a basic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is an equation centered on its own line:
\[ ax + by + cz = 2x + 3y + 4z \]
And here is an equation broken across multiple lines:
\begin{align*}
ax + by + cz
& = 2x + 3y + 4z \\
& = z \left( 2\frac{x}{z} + 3\frac{y}{z} + 4 \right)
\quad \text{(as long as $z \neq 0$)} \\
& = 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\begin{align}` means you don't need to do `\begin{equation}`. Additionally, if you try to nest them, you will get an error.